# DOJO difference between instantiation and using source

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dojo, tree

I am new to DOJO and trying to figure out the difference between these two uses of the seemingly two things.

```
dndController: new dijit.tree.dndSource("dijit.tree.dndSource",{copyOnly:true})
```

and

```
dndController: "dijit.tree.dndSource"
```

The second one works, but when I use the first one, it gives me an error when loading my tree. It says type node is undefined. The reason I want to use the first one though is because I want to set copyOnly to true.

Any answers appreciated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That parameter expects a constructor *function* instead of the object you passed. Perhaps the following would work:

```
dndController: function(arg, params){
    return new dijit.tree.dndSource(
        arg,  // don't mess up with the first parameter
        dojo.mixin({}, params, {copyOnly:true}))
           //create a copy of the params object, but set copyOnly to true
}
```

**Some explanation:**

I actually don't know anything about drag-and-drop on trees. All I did was look at the Tree source code (its at dijit/Tree.js or something like that) to find out where dndController is used. From that point I could find out that is was supposed to be a function that can receive these two parameters (or a string representing the path to such a function...). The actual dijit.tree.dndSource function that is used I just copied from your question statement, hoping it would work.

The dojo.mixin function mixes in all the objects in its 2nd, 3rd, ... arguments into the first argument. By using a new, empty, object as the "receiving" object we have a neat way to make a  shallow copy of params, settting copyOnly without modifying the original params object.

Comment: @missingnoThanks! That worked perfectly. Since I am still new to Dojo/Javascript, I would really appreciate it if you could provide me some more explanation. I have tried looking up the components used (dojo.mixin and source on tree and dndSource). Specificially, these are the points I don't get: What are "arg" and "params" and where are they being passed. Also, what dojo.mixin is operating on, since its first param is empty. Thanks, that was a great answer!

Comment: That does help clarify thing. I especially like that you explained the thought process (if I could give a second up-vote or something I would). But I am still confused on what value "arg" and "params" have and where they are passed from. This might be a fundamental javascript understanding problem, but I am not sure.

Comment: I also don't know what they do, LOL. When the dndController function is called inside the Tree (check the source code) it receives `this` as the first parameter and a `params` variable as the second (I don't know where the params comes from - you can check it out if you want). So when I had to chose argument names I just borrowed the params name for the second and used a very lazy `arg` name for the first (could be x, foo or whatever anyway...).