# DOJO: Explanation of function parameters

Tags: javascript, function, dojo

So I asked an earlier question ([Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7395197/879485)). I got a great answer that did exactly what I wanted. However, since I am new to Javascript/Dojo, I wasn't able to fully understand it, and neither was the answerer of the question.

My question is: How does the following code work?

```
dndController: function(arg, params){
    return new dijit.tree.dndSource(
        arg,  // don't mess up with the first parameter
        dojo.mixin({}, params, {copyOnly:true}))
           //create a copy of the params object, but set copyOnly to true
}
```

So the part bugging me the most is the "args" and "params" parameters. I don't understand where they come from and what they mean or represent. (If there needs to be more context to the code, I can edit the question later, so just post it in the comments). Also, why couldn't I just use the `new dijit.tree.dndSource` directly and why did I need to use the function to return it?

Thanks

Comment: Look for whatever calls `dndController`. You likely *could* use `new ...` directly, but which is shorter?

Comment: Its seems like its in the constructor to tree. I am overriding the default dndController in the declaration of the tree.

Comment: It looks like Dojo is using `dndController` as a point of extension to allow arbitrary `dndSource` definitions. Here you're using the stock `tree.dndSource`. So the `this` arg parameter would be the tree itself, required by `tree.dndSource` so its implementation can be used by arbitrary trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at dijit/Tree.js in the dojo source.

in Tree.js, inside the postCreate function (which is used by any widget as a part of the dijit lifecycle):

```
if(this.dndController){
    if(dojo.isString(this.dndController)){
        this.dndController = dojo.getObject(this.dndController);
    }
    var params={};
    for(var i=0; i<this.dndParams.length;i++){
        if(this[this.dndParams[i]]){
            params[this.dndParams[i]] = this[this.dndParams[i]];
        }
    }
    this.dndController = new this.dndController(this, params);
}
```

You'll see a section which checks what the `dndController` property is.  If it is a string it sets the dndController attribute to the function that creates the class that the string describes (this is what `dojo.getObject(string)` is doing).

For example if this.dndController was the string `"my.special.dnd.controlller"`, it would return the function that, when called instantiates a new instance of `my.special.dnd.controller`.

It then copies some parameters into an object, followed by executing the function that was either:

(1) looked up via dojo.getObject

(2) uses the custom function you passed in.

I would assume the maintainer of this widget does it this way as some people only need to specify a specific class to use as the dnd controller, whereas others need to do some something more custom based on what parameters the Tree was passed.